# Nuxt3 - accessing Vuex store from middleware?

Tags: vuex, nuxt3, nuxt-middleware

How can I access a Vuex store from within a middleware?

I know Nuxt3 suggests using Pinia, but I had problems installing/integrating it due to dependencies conflicts, so I used the ol' good Vuex.

Problem is, in Nuxt3 my middleware has no access to the `context` object but just to the routes that are being navigated to/from.

So the question probably became: is that even possible or am I enforced to use Pinia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a plugin to handle that instead. It works even on present Nuxt 3.6.5

Here:

```
import { useUserStore } from '@/store';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxt => {
    const store = useUserStore(nuxt.$pinia);

    addRouteMiddleware('my-middleware', async (to, from) => {
        // TODO:
    }, { global: true });
});
```

For non global middleware you just remove the global flag,thus

```
  addRouteMiddleware('named-test', () => {
    console.log('this named middleware was added in a plugin')
  })
})
```

Edited:

You could then save the plugin with .client suffix so it only becomes active on the client side

```
auth.client.js
```

Here a link to help https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware#adding-middleware-dynamically